# In Falcor how to work with database?

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, falcor, falcor-router

I am new to falcor data fetching framework. I tried with few example when I request for something like

```
model.get(["contacts", {0..2}, "name"])
     .then(response => {
        this.state.list = response.json.contacts;
        this.setState(this.state);
      });
```

at server side

```
let data = {
    contacts: [
        {name: "ABC"},
        {name: "XYZ"},
        {name: "PQR"}
    ]
};

let contactsRouter = Router.createClass([
    {
        route: 'contacts[{integers:contactIndexes}]',
        get: (pathSet) => {
            let results = [];
            pathSet.contactIndexes.forEach(contactIndex => {
                if (data.contacts.length > contactIndex) {
                    results.push({
                        path: ["contacts", contactIndex, "name"],
                        value: data.contacts[contactIndex].name
                    });
                }
            });
            return results;
        }
    },
    {
        route: 'contacts.add',
        call: (callPath, args) => {
            var newContact = args[0];

            data.contacts.push({name: newContact})
            return [
                {
                    path: ['contacts', data.contacts.length-1, 'name'],
                    value: newContact
                },
                {
                    path: ['contacts', 'length'],
                    value: data.contacts.length
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]);
```

I'm getting data & able to do other operations too.
My question is I want to do same CRUD operations with MongoDB instead from

data.contacts

how i construct JSON Graph object data should come from database schema. hope my question is cleared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to simply do a database query inside the route's `get` function:

```
{
    route: 'contacts[{integers:contactIndexes}]',
    get: (pathSet) => {
        const data = db.get('myModel', (err, res) => {
            return res
        })
        let results = [];
        pathSet.contactIndexes.forEach(contactIndex => {  
            if (data.contacts.length > contactIndex) {
                results.push({
                    path: ["contacts", contactIndex, "name"],
                    value: data.contacts[contactIndex].name
                });
            }
        });
        return results;
    }
}
```

Made a simple [repo](https://github.com/luandro/falcor-couchdb-api) using Falcor and CouchDB. It should be enough to understand how it should be done in MongoDB.